# rails app styling all fails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have  a rails application that I just moved to a server. Somewhere some of the configuration is off and my web pages styling is all not loading. The rails console gives out: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/search-icon.png")` for every asset (images, javascript, and stylesheet).

Where could this be occuring?

The main difference is that I am launching in production mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3.1 brought it 'Asset Pipeline'. With its introduction, serving of assets (images, stylesheets, javascripts) works differently in production.

In development/test environments, rails application handles serving the assets by concatenating, minifying and/or compressing based on the configuration.

But in production, it is expected that the assets be precompiles to the public directory with the following rake task:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and your application can be configured for assets to be served by the rails application or (by convention) by the web server.

Looks like you have not precompiled the assets, which is why rails is unable to serve the non-existent files.

Visit [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/asset_pipeline.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

> Where could this be occurring

To add to the answers, it's because of [`asset fingerprinting`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark).

Whenever you push your app to production, by default, Rails will concatenate your assets into any [manifest files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) you've defined (typically `application.css`):

> The technique sprockets uses for fingerprinting is to insert a hash of the content into the name, usually at the end. For example a CSS file global.css
>
> ```
> global-908e25f4bf641868d8683022a5b62f54.css
> ```

This works the same for your `image`, `js`, `font`, `video` & `audio` assets.

---

When you call an image asset in production, Rails *only* has access to the `public` folder (`precompilation` puts all assets into `public/assets`):

`public/assets/images/search-icon[[hash]].png`

Calling `url("assets/images/search-icon.png")` in CSS, or *explicitly referencing* the image in any part of your app won't work. You have to reference the precompiled assets, which can be best achieved with the various [`asset_path` helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html) (such as [`image-url`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass)):

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
.class {
  background: image-url("search-icon.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the asset helpers, so the paths do not match the asset pipeline paths generated in production. Have a read of [The Asset Pipeline Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), especially the [Coding Links to Assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets) section.

You haven't shown the code you're using to generate the paths, so I can't offer a specific solution, but the above links have the information for CSS with ERB as well as if you're using Sass templates.